# Ruby выдает ошибки при попытке скомпилировать код Sass

Tags: sass

[image]

Помогите, пожалуйста. Не могу решить проблему(смотрите картинку) Постоянно выскакивает ошибка, Sass не компилируется. Реально не знаю что делать!

Comment: Пожалуйста, будьте вежливы к другим участникам: вставляйте сообщения об ошибках текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема Ваша в кодировке, винде, и названием папки на русском языке.
Т.е. проблема в том что компилятор саса пытается создать что-то в каталоге C:\users\Алина, но вот в виду не понятных факторов "Алина" он преобразует к кодировке 866 и получается "└ышэр", а этого каталога нету, и нет прав его создавать

Варианты решения:

1. Действовать в винде от имени пользователя в латинице (Не "Алина" например, а "Ivan"
2. Попробовать выполнить скрипт от имени супер пользователя
3. Развернуть руби на виртуальной машине под управлением linux (Там кодировка файловой системы в utf-8, да и подобных граблей в принципе нету)

Comment: Спасибо, думаю linux для  будет оптимальным решением проблемы!

Comment: От себя добавлю, что в VirtualBox есть шикарный Seamless Mode, который накладывает окна из виртуальной машины на рабочий стол хоста, чтобы было удобнее работать с окнами виртуальной машины.